# Get all inline events from HTML string

Tags: javascript, regex, parsing, dom

I'm trying to get a list of all inline event tags from an HTML `<body>` string, how would I be able to do this?

Example:

```
 <a onclick='foo()'></a>
```

I'd want to extract `onclick='foo()'`.

Is it possible with REGEX or any other alternatives?

Comment: yes **[take a look here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454)**

Comment: Yes, I've read that,, wondering if there are any alternatives.
Although events are very constant in terms of inline, so REGEX will probably work.

Comment: You can iterate over each element and access its `onXXXXX` attribute...

Comment: Couldn't, cause I'm doing this in Node.js  and the JSDOM module ironically strips inline events.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's one. The event-thing will be group 1:

```
<\w+[^>]+(on[a-z]+=["'][^"']+["'])[^>]*>
```

Comment: That's weird, works fine for me. Have you tried it with case insensitive search?

Comment: If the problem is the group, btw, you could use a little more naive regex like `(on[a-z]+=["'][^"']+["'])(?=[^>]*>)`

Answer (score 0):

You should let the browser do the parsing, for example like this:

```
var doc = document.implementation.createHTMLDocument('');
doc.documentElement.innerHTML = '<body onload="alert(1)"></body>'; // your string here
```

Then get the `on*` attributes using DOM methods:

```
var attributes = Array.prototype.slice.call(doc.body.attributes);
for (var i = 0; i < attributes.length; i++) {
    if (/^on/.test(attributes[i].name)) {
        console.log(attributes[i].name, attributes[i].value);
    }
}
```

Comment: I agree you should use the DOM or some library if you're actually in a browser. Otoh, if you're searching through the code for inline event handlers to replace them with something else, regex is probably easier.

Comment: The reason why I need this is that I'm doing this in node.js and ironically the jsdom module is ignoring inline events.